# Wordpress dashboard display option in edit page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XjL9.jpg)

point 1 The screen option does not work properly or it didn't even work i am continuously clicking it but nothing works out.

number 2 i don't see the option for going to next page like i usually see .

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got an answer actually the problem was i have accidently made the number of post per page 600 so it was taking time too load so all the pages are not showing in single page they were not even getting load at the first place.
so i move to option (Draft) in which there was less post so at that category display screen works fine then i chose number of post to display to 50 after that i worked .[image: Here to show how i did it]

Gone to Draft option then make the number from screen option to 50. and it worked. now i can see all the pages i had posted.